# How I can execute commands inside container by api

Tags: linux, bash, api, docker

I wonder if it is possible execute command (for example **ls**) inside container by docker api.

Comment: You mean like `docker exec containername command `?

Answer (score 0):

You can access container shell with docker exec command
-it parameter allow interactive access inside container

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
```

To get container name:

```
docker ps -a
```

Comment: I know but I want use docker api by http man